# convert incoming text timestamp from rsyslog to timestamp for postrgesql

Tags: postgresql, rsyslog, timestamp-with-timezone

I have logs from various linux servers being fed by rsyslog to a PostgreSQL database.  The incoming timestamp is an rsyslog'd RFC3339 formatted time like so: `2020-10-12T12:01:18.162329+02:00`.

In the original test setup of the database logging table, I created that timestamp field as 'text'.  Most things I need parsed are working right, so I was hoping to convert that timestamp table column from text to a timestamp datatype (and retain the subseconds and timezone if possible).

The end result should be a timestamp datatype so that I can do date-range queries using PostgreSQL data functions.

Is this doable in PostgreSQL 11?  Or is it just better to re-create the table with the correct timestamp column datatype to begin with?

Thanks in advance for any pointers, advice, places to look, or snippets of code.

Relevant rsyslog config:

```
$template CustomFormat,"%timegenerated:::date-rfc3339% %syslogseverity-text:::uppercase% %hostname% %syslogtag% %msg%\n"
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate CustomFormat

...

template(name="rsyslog" type="list" option.sql="on") {
  constant(value="INSERT INTO log (timestamp, severity, hostname, syslogtag, message)
    values ('")
    property(name="timegenerated" dateFormat="rfc3339")  constant(value="','")
    property(name="syslogseverity-text" caseConversion="upper")  constant(value="','")
    property(name="hostname")  constant(value="','")
    property(name="syslogtag")  constant(value="','")
    property(name="msg")  constant(value="')")
}
```

and the log table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE public.log
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('log_id_seq'::regclass),
    "timestamp" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" DEFAULT timezone('UTC'::text, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
    severity character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    hostname character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    syslogtag character varying(24) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    program character varying(24) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    process text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    message text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT log_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

some sample data already fed into the table (ignore the timestamps in the messsage, they are done with an independent handmade logging system by my predecessor):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in theory convert the `TEXT` column to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` with `ALTER TABLE .. ALTER COLUMN ... SET DATA TYPE ... USING`, e.g.:

```
postgres=# CREATE TABLE tstest (tsval TEXT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE

postgres=# INSERT INTO tstest values('2020-10-12T12:01:18.162329+02:00');
INSERT 0 1

postgres=# ALTER TABLE tstest
             ALTER COLUMN tsval SET DATA TYPE TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
             USING tsval::TIMESTAMPTZ;
ALTER TABLE

postgres=# \d tstest
                       Table "public.tstest"
 Column |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 tsval  | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |


postgres=# SELECT * FROM tstest ;
             tsval
-------------------------------
 2020-10-12 12:01:18.162329+02
(1 row)
```

PostgreSQL can parse the `RFC3339` format, so subsequent inserts should just work:

```
postgres=# INSERT INTO tstest values('2020-10-12T12:01:18.162329+02:00');
INSERT 0 1

postgres=# SELECT * FROM tstest ;
             tsval
-------------------------------
 2020-10-12 12:01:18.162329+02
 2020-10-12 12:01:18.162329+02
(2 rows)
```

But note that any bad data in the table (i.e. values which cannot be parsed as timestamps) will cause the `ALTER TABLE` operation to fail, so you should consider verifying the values before converting the data. Something like `SELECT "timestamp"::TIMESTAMPTZ FROM public.log` would fail with an error like `invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "somebadvalue"`.

Also bear in mind this kind of `ALTER TABLE` requires a table rewrite which may take some time to complete (depending on how large the table is), and which requires a `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock, rendering the table inaccessible for the duration of the operation.

If you want to avoid a long-running `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock, you could probably do something like this (not tested):

- add a new `TIMESTAMPTZ` column (adding a column doesn't rewrite the table and is fairly cheap provided you don't use a volatile default value)
- creating a trigger to copy any values inserted into the original column
- copy the existing values (using a bunch of batched updateds like `UPDATE public.foo SET newlog = log::TIMESTAMPTZ`
- (in a single transaction) drop the trigger and the existing column, and rename the new column to the old one

Comment: at this point, the logging system is still in flux, so i can delete all the current data without worrying about bad data.   the question remains:  alter the column *now* then clear out the table, or clear first then alter.   I guess it does not really matter?

Comment: well i took the chance and just ran the alter table command on the field.   worked perfectly, so i don't think i even need to clear the table - so far.   thanks for your response!